# How do I use jQuery Validate directly, without the submit button?

Tags: jquery-validate

I have done various tests and I have found that the jQuery `validate` function works only with the submit button.

Am I right? If yes how can I use the jQuery validate plugins without the submit button?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the method [valid()](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid) to invoke the validator directly.

It will return bool indicating whether the form is valid or not.

Here is an example, from jQuery documentation:

```
$("#myform").validate();
$("a.check").click(function() {
    alert("Valid: " + $("#myform").valid());
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

When you call the [`validate` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) on the [jQuery validate plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) it returns an instance of [`Validator`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#Validator) which you should store.  When you need to, you can call the [`form`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/form) or [`showErrors`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/showErrors#errors) methods on the `Validator` instance to either validate the form, or validate the form and show the errors respectively.

Comment: Can you give me an example if possible please?