# Struts 2 XML Validation

Tags: java, xml, validation, struts2

I'm getting started with Struts 2 and I am trying to validate 2 text fields using Struts xml validators.

```
<s:textfield name="userName" id="userName" label="User Name">
<s:textfield name="passWord" id="userName" label="Password">
```

I was able to validate fields by clicking submit button.

Is it possible to validate fields even before clicking submit button? Conditions would be: when you try to enter password without userName, validate userName field and display error message if it's empty.

any help would appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at jQuery Validation plugin: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation.

Comment: For without using submit button, you need to use jquery validation.
After clicking submit button you need to use struts2 validations.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do it before the request, that is, on the client side. You could use `Javascript` with a `OnChange` or `OnKeyDown` event on the textboxes. The triggered method could invalidate the submission and display error messages using DOM.
Just by curiosity, why would you need to do this exactly ?

Comment: OP wants validation to take place "before clicking submit button".

Comment: My bad. You just have to use a different event. I'll change my answer.

Comment: If you attach event on the button when do you think it will be triggered?

Answer (score 0):

```
Regarding this question in stack overflow so many discussions are already there (but not   in strtus2  it is in JQuery).
```

I am giving those links you can refer it from here,
  [How do I use jQuery Validate directly, without the submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340127/how-do-i-use-jquery-validate-directly-without-the-submit-button.)

[jquery validate: IF form valid then show submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031376/jquery-validate-if-form-valid-then-show-submit-button.)

[Hide submit button until form is valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690947/hide-submit-button-until-form-is-valid.)